# check whether the match is found using re.search() for exapmles below

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract numbers from strings that do not start with `order` and `cart` and that should not end with `dollar`.

I have the following code:

```
import re
pattern = "(^.*\b(?:cart|order)\b.*)(\b\d{2,12}\b)"
text1 = ('the cart number is 1234 and 4567 that it!')
text2 = ("order number note down 12345")
text3 = "credit card is 0000 and 3456"
text4 = "the 4567"
text5 = "i got 245 dollar"

result = re.search(pattern, text4)
print(result)
```

Expected output match

```
text3 0000 3456
text4 4567
```

Can we achieve expected output by passing one example at a time using `re` module?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want ? Are you satisfied with your current regex expression ? If so, what do you want to know ?

Comment: i dont want number followed by cart or order word and also i dont want number followed by dollar word as mentioned in examples.But for any other words it should match as shown in expected output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with two regexps, one will check if there is a `cart` or `order` at the start with an optional article or `dollar` at the end, and another will extract the numbers:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile( r"\b\d{2,12}\b" )
pattern_valid = re.compile( r"^\s*(?:(the|an?)\s+)?(cart|order)\b|\bdollar\s*$", re.I )
texts = ['the cart number is 1234 and 4567 that it!', 
    "order number note down 12345",
    "credit card is 0000 and 3456",
    "the 4567",
    "i got 245 dollar"]
for text in texts:
    if not pattern_valid.search(text):
        print(text, pattern.findall(text), sep=" => ")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WxJuhT). Output:

```
credit card is 0000 and 3456 => ['0000', '3456']
the 4567 => ['4567']
```

The `^\s*(?:(the|an?)\s+)?(cart|order)\b|\bdollar\s*$` regex matches an optional `the` or `a`/`an` article at the start followed with the word `order` or `cart` or the word `dollar` at the end of string. If there is a match, the string is not processed. If there is no match, the second regex extracts all 2-12 digit numbers that are whole words from the string.

Comment: Is it possible to write it in a single pattern instead of two patterns ? Thank you

Comment: @Dip No, it is not possible with `re` since you need multiple number matches, but it is possible with PyPi regex module. Can you `pip install regex`?